# Send multiple URL parameters using ajax get request

Tags: html, ajax, parameters, get

I'm developing ajax page for my project. in this page i want to send a ajax request with multiple url parameters. and i want to get this url parameters from html text boxes. when I pass the parameters using code directly it working fine. but when I called the parameters from HTML textboxes it's not working.

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
 // xmlhttp.open("GET","portal.php?searccategory=Birdid&searchValue=2",true);
xmlhttp.open("GET","portal.php?searccategory="+searccategory+"&searchValue="+searchValue,true);

xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


        <select name="searccategory1" >
                                    <option value="Species">Species</option>
                                    <option value="Birdid">ID</option>
                                    <option value="Age">Age</option>
                                    <option value="Sex">Sex</option>
                                    <option value="Location">Location</option>
                                    <option value="all">all</option>
                                </select>
         <input type="text" id="searccategory" required>
         <input type="text" id="searchValue" required>


<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when the parameters are got from HTML?

Comment: but when I'm using xmlhttp.open("GET","portal.php?searccategory=Birdid&searchValue=2",true); it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if it help for you, the searccategory and searchValue return the DOM element. if you want to get the value please use the `searccategory.value` and `searchValue.value`. or `document.getElementById("searccategory").value` and `document.getElementById("searchValue").value`

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","portal.php?searccategory="+searccategory.value+"&searchValue="+searchValue.value,true);
```

or

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","portal.php?searccategory="+document.getElementById("searccategory").value+"&searchValue="+document.getElementById("searchValue").value,true);
```